# Exception raised during XML rendering in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I'm trying to view my XML file in Eclipse, I get this error:

```
Exception raised during rendering: Can't make a decor toolbar out of MockView
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Error Log)
- android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
```

I have tried to restart Eclipse, but the error is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I did not get Why you are still using the Eclipse , I have stopped using eclipse now its time to shift up to the Android studio for you. I think I have face the same error in android studio too and then the only trick that only work for me to make my xml rendered properly is the following trick

you should change the android version for rendering to the 21 or may be more latter: see [image: this]

I think in Eclipse you can easily find this..   .